# trying to use boto copy to s3 unless file exists

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

in my code below,
fn2 is the local file and "my_bucket_object.key" is a list of files in my s3 bucket.

I am looking at my local files, taking the latest one by creation date and then looking at the bucket and I only want to copy the latest one there (this is working) but not if it exists already. What is happening is that, even if the file is there in the bucket, the latest file is still getting copied, overwriting the one in the bucket with the same name.
the filename of the latest file is "bats6.csv"
I figured that specifying 'in' and 'not in' conditions, this would ensure that the file did not get copied if one with the same name is already there, but this isnt working.
Here is the code. Thanks alot.

```
 import boto3
 import botocore
 import glob, os
 import datetime
 import os

 exchanges = ["bats"]

 for ex in exchanges:
     csv_file_list = glob.glob(f"H:\SQL_EXPORTS\eod\candles\{ex}\\*.csv")
     latest_file = max(csv_file_list, key=os.path.getctime)

     path = f'H:\\SQL_EXPORTS\\eod\\candles\\{ex}\\'
     fileBaseName = os.path.basename(latest_file).split('.')[0]

     fn = path + fileBaseName + ".csv"
     fn2 = fileBaseName + ".csv"

     print(fn2)

     s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
     my_bucket = s3.Bucket(f'eod-candles-{ex}')

     for my_bucket.object in my_bucket.objects.all():
         print(my_bucket.object.key)
         if fn2 not in my_bucket.object.key:
             #s3.meta.client.upload_file(fn, my_bucket, fn2)
             s3.meta.client.upload_file(fn, f'eod-candles-{ex}', fn2)
         elif fn2 in my_bucket.object.key:
             print("file already exists")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but `for my_bucket.object in my_bucket.objects.all():` looks a little strange. The `for` loop is returning an `object`, but you are storing it inside the `my_bucket` Python object. Why should a bucket have a property that is an object? Perhaps just store it in a new variable (`for object in my_bucket.objects.all():`)?

Comment: I don't understand your logic for testing whether an object exists in S3. The `for` loop is looping through each object in the bucket, but your code is **checking every object** to determine whether it has a Key that contains `fn2`. For example, if `fn2 = bats6.csv`, then the `for` loop will first return a Key that contains `bats5.csv`. Since this does not match `fn2`, the code will upload `bats6.csv`. In the next iteration of the loop, the Key will be `bats6.csv` and the code will say "file already exists". The code should only upload if _none_ of the objects matches the name (not _every_).

Comment: yes, your right. I also suspected the issue that you identified in paragraph 2. But how do I check whether fn2 matches none of the items in the list? (any of the keys really)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a *List* of the object keys and then check whether it exists:

```py
object_keys = [object.key for object in my_bucket.objects.all()]
if fn2 not in object_keys:
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(fn, f'eod-candles-{ex}', fn2)
```

Comment: thanks, I will try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: You can also use `set` instead of `list`. Since, for searching an element in a collection, sets are faster as they have been implemented using hash tables.